# How to remove the arrow from the default wordpress permalink

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Probably a basic question but how do I remove the arrow in the top tab on a wordpress permalink?

ie:[image]

Comment: please give example properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The separator is the first argument of [`wp_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_title).

You can use something like `<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>` to remove the separator.

Answer (score 0):

Does your post or page title have those characters? To edit the permalink you can click on the Edit button just beside your permalink.